# BJT AC analysis

Tags: ac, bjt, biasing

Why while performing bjt's AC signal analysis we consider the base current as same as it is derived due to **DC biasing of bjt**(when there is no AC input applied),the applied AC signal must **change its values instead**!?

Answer (score 1):

Quite a misconception here. AC analysis assumes a linearized model where all non-linear laws are replaced with linear equations. Those linear equations are derived at the DC operating point. The DC component of the base current is just that DC bias current, the analysis results are calculated assuming an ac component (=the signal).

AC analysis can give in practice acceptable results, if the voltages and currents vary a little in percents around the DC operating point values. In other words the DC component of any current or voltage is much larger than the AC component.

In math they say "this is a first order approximation, the second and higher order derivatives are rejected"

AC analysis is not valid for large signals. Then the full non-linear analysis must be used. In circuit simulators it's often called "Time domain" or "Transient" analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It is changing of course. See this:

**Here is AC analysis in nutshell:**

Before proceeding to AC analysis, we do DC analysis (with shorted AC sources and opened coupling capacitors) and make sure that our transistor is biased in the right operating region. We then calculate base and output voltages and currents. These are known as DC bias voltages or currents. Now we introduce our AC input source and the corresponding coupling capacitors. Now we have to superimpose or add that AC voltage over to our previously calculated DC base voltage (superposition theorem right !?). Consequently, base current is also superimposed. The same happens at the output too. Depending on the gain, the amplifed AC signal is superimposed on to the previously calculated DC bias voltage at the output. If there is a coupling capacitor at the output, that DC bias voltage is nullified and thus we get the amplified AC component.

Answer (score 0):

Small signal analysis assumes that the applied ac signal is small enough that the operating point is not changed. If this is not the case the analysis not valid.